# Prolonging the exothermic reaction between calcium oxide and water

Tags: experimental-chemistry, energy, heat

Is it possible to generate 10-minutes of heat using very small amounts of CaO and water? This is an exothermic reaction.

I've done this experiment at home, but it is very short-lived. I'm trying to understand the ratio of reactants I need to generate heat that lasts long (like heat packs.)

Comment: You can make heat release semi-continuous by adding stoichiometric amount of water drop-wise for 10 min.

Comment: Perhaps a include a slower reaction whose product is CaO?

Comment: Use larger particles of CaO. Or, get cement clinker (which is rich in CaO), and grind the 1 inch chunks to whatever size works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are funnels with an Archimedic spiral at the bottom -- in principle quite similar to a truck with a concrete mixer.  So, provided you are able to grind CaO into a fine powder, slowly turning this screw will add CaO into a receiver flask below.  Like this one:

[image]

([reference](https://chemglass.com/funnels-powder-addition?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1))